# Item.get() if key can have multiple names

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I need to get the value of key's in my dictionary. The thing is the dict keys can change according to sensors.

```
possible keys: light_missing, dark_missing, pixel_missing
```

So I want to loop over all records and always get the value of the 'missing' data.

How can I do this with:

```
item.get("missing")
```

Answer (score 0):

### Data

I suppose that you have a dictionary like this:

```
item = { 
'light_missing': 1, 
'dark_missing': 0, 
'pixel_missing': 0, 
'light': 0, 
'dark': 1, 
'pixel': 1 
}
```

### Computation

And you want to filter it, getting only the objects with a key ending with 'missing', like this:

```
for key, value in item.items():
    if key.endswith('missing'):
        print(key, value)
```

Or, if you want your result as a list:

```
result = [(key, value) for key, value in item.items() if key.endswith('missing')]
```

### Output

The output from this snippet is:

```
light_missing 1
dark_missing 0
pixel_missing 0
```

Or, if used the "list alternative";

```
[('light_missing', 1), ('dark_missing', 0), ('pixel_missing', 0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works fine

```
import re

dict = { 
'light_missing': 1, 
'dark_missing': 0, 
'pixel_missing': 0, 
'light': 0, 
'dark': 1, 
'pixel': 1 
}

search_key_pattern = '^.+(_missing)$'

for key in dict.keys():
    if re.search(search_key_pattern,key):
       print(key+" "+str(dict.get(key)))
```